# Use of the Peclet number in FEFlow as a mesh-quality metric

Tags: modelling, flow

The user manual for FEFlow (v7.0) states

> "In transport models, the elemental distribution Péclet Number is
>   available which can be used to check whether the spatial
>   discretization is sufficiently fine for a specific transport problem."

However, it is not clear whether a higher or lower Peclet number indicates an appropriate mesh for the transport problem.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

From the FEFlow forums - (Bjorn Kaiser)

> The finer the mesh the lower the Péclet number. As a very rough rule of thumb the literature often said that the grid Péclet number should not exceed a value of 2. From my experience, I do not always insist to satisfy a number smaller than 2. Other factors as such as the type of physical problem (e.g. linear non-linear), the degree of required accuracy, computational resources may also play a role in the mesh design. Anyway, the Péclet provides a useful quantitative measure on whether or not the mesh is fine enough for a transport model.

http://forum.mikepoweredbydhi.com/index.php?topic=18550.0